# Save and Retrieve Data Using Cookies

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to save clicked courses into a cookies named 'preferred' and then click a link to display saved list in SaveView.js component. Right now, my problem is cookies.get('preferred') is undefined. I am not sure how to retrieve the cookies value in a new component. My sandbox link is https://u2sjw.csb.app/#/
Please advise! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using this npm package for your cookies, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie then you should follow the instructions given which are

```
const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(['cookie-name']);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using class component in App.js, how to use react-hooks for useCookies?

Comment: @user788448 check under the title `Simple Example with Higher-Order Component`